# The function get_option() does not pull a value from my DB

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an option value in the `wp_options` table as such: `option_name` . `twitter_feed` . and the value is there in the options value column. But when I run the following in my code, I get `false`:

```
$tf =  get_option('twitter_feed');
var_dump($tf);
```

I have access to my DB and I can see that there is an option named `twitter_feed` and there is a value. The value starts with a format of:

> a:20:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":28:{s:10:"created_at";s:30:"Tue Sep 19 22:16:26 +0000 2017";s:2:"id";i:910266359799525376;s:6:"id_str";s:18:"910266359799525376";s:4:"text";s:70:"We can't wait for the Grand Opening on Oct 19!'

Does the format that is saved in the DB has anything to do with not being able to pull the value? I would assume I would at least get an error and not `false`.

I also have a `facebook_feed` value that works. It is also an option in the `wp_options` table of `facebook_feed` and that value starts with a format of:

> a:25:{i:0;a:6:{s:7:"message";s:412:""Our scientific and research-based training and programs were devised to help

How can I access the value of my `twitter_feed` value?

Comment: Could you try replace the meta value in DB by a simple INT and see if it works ?

Comment: Could have something to do with invalid JSON?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like serialized data. See:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this: 
`$ff = get_option('twitter_feed');
$ff = unserialize($ff);
var_dump($ff);`

the same false. Since I have access to the DB, I grabbed the original twitter feed value and save it to a text editor and then copied the facebook feed value and placed it in the twitter_feed options value. Still FALSE. This makes no sense. AS I have a facebook_feed option and a twitter_feed option both with the same value in my wp_options table and only the facebook_feed works. I have deleted all of the transients in wp_options table thinking this might be an issue but no luck.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well after many hours I finally got it working. I inherited this WP site and it seems to have been coded by someone who just learned OOP. Got to give them props for trying but Many issues. So I created a brand new function to consume the Twitter API and save the new feed in my twitter_feed options value and that worked. Not sure if the data was corrupted, but when I would try to pull the original data out I would receive a FALSE value. Now with the new data feed saved, it works.

Thanks Paul for the suggestion.